# How to differentiate between 'right click using mouse' AND 'context menu key press on physical keyboard'

Tags: jquery, contextmenu, keypress, right-click

How do I differentiate between right click using mouse and context menu key press on a physical keyboard?

Using this code I tried printing event in console

```
$('#'+inputId).bind('contextmenu', function(e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

I grabbed some output for the above code-

**For right click using the mouse it is-**

1. button: 2
2. originalEvent: MouseEvent
3. type: "contextmenu"
4. which: 3

**For context menu key press on the keyboard it is-**

1. button: 2
2. originalEvent: MouseEvent
3. type: "contextmenu"
4. which: 3

I want to perform some action only when 'context menu key' is pressed on the physical keyboard. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hiya there This will help you to capture the difference: **Working Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/pPnME/1/

I have tested this on Alienware - Chrome, when you will right click you will see the right click alert other wise on keyboard you will see keyborad alert.

Please note: you can identify the click based on `which` property: http://api.jquery.com/event.which/

> For key or mouse events, this property indicates the specific key or
>   button that was pressed.

Hope this fits the cause. `:)`

Also note there are few plugins available to get the shortcut but I would recommend stick to the basic and use the demo I have given if its only to capture both event separately rest demo is all your to play :)

**code**

```
/*
  1 = Left   Mousebutton
  2 = Centre Mousebutton
  3 = Right  Mousebutton
*/
$('input').mousedown(function(e) {
    if (e.which === 3) {
        alert('rightclick'); /* Right Mousebutton was clicked! */
    }
});
$('input').bind('contextmenu', function(e) {
    alert('keyboard yeah');
    //console.log(e);
});​
```

Comment: Thanks @Tats_innit, on my Ubuntu machine it is working for keyboard but for right click using mouse I see 2 alerts first on mousedown and second on bind.

Comment: @ManojL Hiya, hmm, I reckon jsfiddle is down temporary for maintenance - how about returning `return false` in the first mousedown event **OR** bind the second `contextmenu` binding with `keyup` evet, funny enough it actually is working fine in my alienware, `:))` but this idea will totally help you. lemme know how it goes

Comment: Yeah jsfiddle looks down at moment. I will try again my pc and let you know...  I think $('input').unbind('contextmenu'); in mousedown event should do the trick!

Comment: Hiya @ManojL indeed that will else you can `return false` after the first alert `:)` you know it better for you application anyways, have a nice one!

Comment: Hiya @ManojL try this man that will suffice: http://jsfiddle.net/pPnME/11/ hope this helps `:)`

Comment: Thanks again @Tats_innit, but I still see 2 alerts first on mousedown and second on bind FOR second jsfiidle also :(

Comment: lol hmm `:)` I reckon avoid using `unbind` coz you will end up `binding` again: try this: http://jsfiddle.net/pPnME/13/ using `stopPropogation()` api.

Answer (score 0):

you can check also if a key is pressed `keyPressed` is the event.

if no, is mouse event, if yes is contextmenu key

Edit: the keycode for contextMenu is 93