# Cross-browser distinguishing between right-click and context menu key

Tags: javascript

Looking for a cross-browser way to distinguish between right-click and the context menu key on a Windows machine.  Here's what I have so far, but it's not perfect:

```
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', (event) => {
  // distinguish between right-click and context menu key here
});
```

**IE, Edge:** is context menu key if `event.clientX <= 0 && event.clientY <= 0`

**FF, Safari:** is context menu key if `event.which === 1`

**Chrome:** is context menu key if `event.which === 0`

This isn't perfect because *technically* a user could mouse right-click in the top left of their window, the event location would be (0, 0), and my logic would think that it was a keypress on IE, Edge, and FF.  I'm looking for something slightly more robust and less complicated.  Does it exist?  I don't want to have to manage a second event handler on mousedown or keydown to distinguish between the events, I'd rather just use the `contextmenu` event if possible.

Comment: you could bind multiple event handlers and tie them together.... or live with 0,0

Comment: Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/pPnME/1/ -- taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11449606/how-to-differentiate-between-right-click-using-mouse-and-context-menu-key-pre

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the button code, and pointerId (to Edge, detects whether the mouse was triggered in the event), here is the code [tested]:

```
//declaring the event
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', (event) => {
//get Edge 
    if(window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Edge") > -1){
        switch(event.pointerId) {
            case 0:
                //this is context key!!
                console.log("Context Key")
                break;
            case 1:
                //this is right click!!
                console.log("Right click")
                break;
    }
    }else{
         switch(event.button) {
             case 0:
                 //this is context key!!
                 console.log("Context Key")
                 break;
             case 2:
                 //this is right click!!
                 console.log("Right click")
                 break;
        }
    }  
});
```